# Java reflection - Android classes not found

Tags: java, android, reflection

I am trying to run reflection to check if some android class exists in Java ( such as Toast ). I am running it from my Command line using this code:

```
String [] packages = new String[] {"java.lang.",
    "android.widget.",
    "android.util.",
    "android.app.",
    "android.view.",
    "android.content."};
for (int i = 0; i < packages.length; i++){
    String package_name = packages[i];
    try {
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(package_name + "Toast");
        System.out.println("class Exists");
        return clazz;
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("class " + package_name + "Toast doesnt exists");
    }
}
```

However, I get the output:
class android.widget.Toast doesn't exists ( but I know it does this is where the class is at)
any ideas?

---

EDIT : I am trying to write a Java class that is not running from Android Studios, but compiles and runs using javac from cmd line.

Comment: If you changed the class you are looking for to something that is definitely loaded in when you are executing the Java program in the console, e.g. java.lang.String, I think you will find the program returns successfully. The JRE is not giving you the android packages.

Comment: Yes I know, this is why I wanted to know if there is a way to access Android classes

Comment: Ah the question didn't explain that. As you edited the question, hopefully my answer below helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are executing this on the command line there is no reason the Android packages/classes should be available to the runtime unless it is explicitly included. The output of your program makes sense - unless you provide the correct Android libraries to the program then there is not going to be  a match when you try to resolve a particular Android class such as `Toast`.

The answer is essentially using Java's classpath effectively. By default, without stating an argument, it is the working directory '.'.

Add to it using -classpath as an argument. Compile naively:

```
javac YourReflectionTest.java
```

as you know the program finds no matches.

If you do this javac will also succeed

```
javac -classpath ".;/opt/android-sdk/platforms/android-21/android.jar" YourReflectionTest.java
```

If you run the program, and try

```
java YourReflectionTest
```

It will still produce the same result. Why? At run-time, there are still no Android classes loaded. You are by default only going to get the java system libraries included in your installation of JDK.

But, if you provide an appropriate path at runtime, then suddenly all the magic happens:

```
java -classpath ".;/opt/android-sdk/platforms/android-21/android.jar" YourReflectionTest
```

Note, Android API level 21 is just an example here and any could be used depending on which features you're trying to test.

Answer (score 0):

When I execute your code, I get get this output:

```
class java.lang.Toast doesnt exists
class Exists
```

Since you iterate over all packages, you get an output for every package, no matter if your class exists or not, and you only stop when you find a match.

I think what you are trying to achieve is to always get only 1 output: either the class exists, or it doesn't. You could do that by creating a method `classExists()` and then using the java stream API to find if any of your packages contains your class `Toast`:

```
public void myMethod() {
    List<String> packages = Arrays.asList(
            "java.lang.",
            "android.widget.",
            "android.util.",
            "android.app.",
            "android.view.",
            "android.content."
    );
    String className = "Toast";
    if (packages.stream().anyMatch(pkg -> classExists(pkg + className))) {
        System.out.println("class exists");
    } else {
        System.out.println("class doesnt exist");
    }
}

boolean classExists(String fullClassName) {
    try {
        Class.forName(fullClassName);
        return true;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I ran my code, I got Toast doesn't exists on all packages.
So I tried running your code and I still get the same ouput - class doesnt exists.
Do you run it from command line \ terminal? is there something special you mentioned in your system variables?

Comment: Hmm that is odd... I ran it in an empty new project in Android Studio. I did not do anything special, just create an new Android Project and that's it.

Comment: Maybe this is it. I am not trying to run it from Android Studios, I am trying to run it using regular Java code. ( because I am using this code without the android studios )

Comment: Classes like Toast are part of the Android runtime libraries that are not going to be available to standard java applications.

Comment: Interesting. Is there any way to download and add some configuration that it will be supported ?

Comment: Then you just need to download the Android SDK, add it to your project ressources and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

A simple method using reflection to check if a class exists or not:

```
private boolean doesClassExist(String name) {
    try {
        Class c = Class.forName(name);
        if (c != null) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // Class not found
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Use Case:

```
boolean classExists = doesClassExist("android.widget.Toast");
```