# Check if a class exists in a specific package

Tags: java, class

I need to check if a class exists in a package.
I know I can use `Class.forName` to check if a class exists, but how do I verify if it is inside a specific package?

Comment: `forName` requires the full qualifies class name. Is that good enough? `Class.getPackage` will give you the runtime package, if you really need that (classes loaded from different class loaders will be in separate runtime packages even if the package name is identical).

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548384/java-get-a-list-of-all-classes-loaded-in-the-jvm

Comment: @Abra the reflection library one?

Comment: The question has 16 different answers. Maybe one (or more than one) can help you. That's why my comment was a question. Do you want to try the suggested solutions in the answers to that question?

Comment: Refer to my answer here [How to check if a class exists in a specific package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74553281/3879456)

Answer (score 1):

### Do not use Class.forName for this.

Class.forName takes a fully qualified name. Fully qualified names *include* the package, but also the outer classes, and therefore, aren't going to work here:

```
package pkg;
class Outer {
    class Inner {}
}
```

results in the fully qualified name, the name you'd have to pass to CFN, for `Inner` is: `Class.forName("pkg.Outer.Inner");` - and how do you tell `Outer` is an outer class and not part of the package name?

Java does *not* have hierarchical packages; there is no relationship between `pkg` and `pkg.subpkg`, so your question hopefully does not involve 'how do I check if the package part **starts** with a certain string', as you shouldn't be asking that question in the java ecosystem.

Thus, let's move away from Class.forName.

Note that the class needs to be available at runtime, or it won't work. "Fortunately", if the class is not available at runtime and you want to determine the package given e.g. a fully qualified class name, because of the above issue with outer and inner classes, **that job is literally impossible**, so if that's what your question boiled down to, you can stop reading: No can do. Let's assume it *is* available at runtime.

### You need a `Class<?>` object.

Each class is represented by an object, of the `java.lang.Class<?>` type. You need to obtain such an object and then you can determine which package it is in.

### Strategy 1: `Class.forName`

`Class.forName("pkg.Outer.Inner")` will get you the Class<?> object and from there you can ask it what its package is, and that *would* get you `pkg`, which you presumably want to know. So that's one way: Given a string representing the fully qualified name of a class, toss it through `Class.forName`, and then operate on the Class object you get out of this.

### Strategy 2: Class literals.

Java has special syntax to obtain the `Class<?>` object given a type reference. So, if you know the type reference when you write your code, you can use this:

```
package pkg;

class Outer {
  class Inner{}
  private static Class<?> innerClassObj = Inner.class;
}
```

However, if you can write it that way, you already know from which package that class is coming from at write time, so that makes your question entirely moot. Why try to figure out at runtime what you already know?

Just in case this is what you wanted to know: Check your imports, and in any major IDE, hold CMD (CTRL on non-macs), and click on the name, it'll take you to where it is defined, and the package will be listed right there. Or just float over it, that works in most IDEs just as well.

### Strategy 3: From an object instance.

All objects have a `.getClass()` method which obtains the `Class<?>` instance representing how the object was created.

**Careful** though!

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>() {
    @Override public boolean add (String other) {
        log.info("Added: {}", other);
        return super.add(other);
    }
};
```

This is perfectly valid, somewhat common and completely innocent java code. However, it means that now invoking `list.getClass()` and then asking for the name of that class gives you something like `com.foo.internal.WhateverClassThatCodeShowedUpIn$1`, because that is technically a subclass, and thus `list` is an instance of that. If you wanted to check if the object is 'of a class that is from the java.util package', then just looking at `list.getClass()` would **incorrectly tell you it is not**.

The fix is to be aware of this and to always (in a `while` loop) go through all the superclasses. `list.getClass().getSuperclass()` would resolve to the exact same instance as `java.util.ArrayList.class` would, invoking getSuperclass on that will get you to `java.util.AbstractList.class`, and from there, `java.lang.Object.class` and then `null`. `java.util.List.class` never shows up here - that is not a class, that is an interface. If you want those too - well, `.getInterfaces()` exists.

So, if you want to know: Is this object compatible with some class that is in some specific package - there is your answer. Only way is to use while loops (and if you want to check interfaces, a queue or recursive method even).

### Strategy 4: Have it be given to you.

You can always just have a method that takes in a `Class<?>` as a parameter. Various APIs out there give you one, as well.

### Okay, I have a `Class<?>` instance, now what?

You could call the `.getPackage()` method on it, but unfortunately the JVM spec dictates that this doesn't actually *have to* return something (it may return `null`). So that's not a great solution. Instead, I suggest you invoke `.getName()` on it, and then go to town on the string you get.

That string you get would be `pkg.Outer$Inner`. You can see how you can derive the package from this:

1. Find the *last* `.`.
2. If it exists, strip that and all after it.
3. If there is no dot at all, it's in the unnamed package.

Voila. That'll leave you with `pkg`.

NB: Take into account the bit written about in strategy 3: For your needs you may have to scan through the superclass and all superinterfaces, recursively.